ESP32 Custom Board - DTR & RTS
I am building a custom board with ESP32-C3-WROOM-02-N4 MCU. I want to use the UART2USB convertor CP2102N-A02-GQFN20R. However, unlike the version in the GQFN28R package, this one lacks the DTR signal used in auto-programming circuitry.
If I understand it correctly, I could change the automatic solution with the manual one (see the schematic), where I have to push the button during every programming of the MCU.
Is this correct?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Have you read the relevant data sheet pertaining to this matter?
